# Greasemonkey, overriding website functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, greasemonkey

i've been reading a lot and have been trying to get this done for about 5 hours now... so here it is

I want to write a script that will override a function dummy() {$.ajax(...)};
on a website.

here is how i'm trying to do it

```
unsafeWindow.dummy = function(data){differantFunction(); $.ajax(...);};

function differantFunction(){
...
}
```

but the dummy function that would have been called up to do something on the original page... now just does nothing.

//update

I tried running that function i'm trying to override trough the adres bar to see what's wrong: (javascript:dummy("..");)

and I get an error telling me $ is undefined but I have jquery on the website and in the userscript... i'm so lost right now

Comment: Shouldn't it be `unsafeWindow.dummy = function(data){...}` ?

Comment: yes it should that's just a typo there i'll edit it now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because the script is running in GM scope.
If you don't use any GM function (like `GM_setValue` or `GM_xmlhttpRequest`), I recommend you to do the following:

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); 
script.type = "text/javascript"; 
script.innerHTML = (<><![CDATA[

// YOUR CODE GOES HERE

]]></>).toString();
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Write the code as a normal script, not a GM script.
I mean, remove all `unsafeWindow` references and related stuff.
This will make the script to run in the correct scope.

BUT if you use GM functions, then you will need to add `unsafeWindow` before every variable in normal scope (like `$`) or do something like the following and pray to make it work:

```
$ = unsafeWindow.$;
//...
```

**PS.:** [Multiline string with E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X) is not supported anymore. Some other options are:
 1) add your code into a function and then use
    [Function.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)
 2) create your code as a separate file and then [add it as a
    resource](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getResourceText)
 3) [add a backslash at the end of each
    line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805113/157873)

Comment: I found a bug in Firebug console, you can't set a breakpoint in a method overridden with Greasemonkey :/

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work at all - could it be because I'm trying to override an event handler?

Comment: You may try to remove the current event handler and add a new one. Ask your own question with some example.

Comment: To get very easy multiline support, just use the new "template literals". `script.innerHTML = \` multiple lines \` `. Please note the "backticks"  >> \` <<.